# Serverless Function looking for node_modules inside function directory instead of node_modules directory

Tags: aws-lambda, puppeteer, serverless, chrome-aws-lambda

I have created a serverless function for generating PDF, and I am using `chrome-aws-lambda` with `puppeteer-core`. But when I call `chromium.puppeteer.launch`, it throws following error:

```
Cannot find module '/path/to/project/.esbuild/.build/src/functions/generatePdf/puppeteer/lib/Browser'
```

`chrome-aws-lambda` trying to look for *puppeteer* in directory of **generatePdf (my function)**. However looking into [source](https://github.com/alixaxel/chrome-aws-lambda/blob/master/source/index.ts) of `chrome-aws-lambda`, I found that it wants to look in relative directory, where chrome-aws-lambda module resides as following:

[image]

So, it wants to load puppeteer libs from same directory, as per source (from github)

[image]

Currently, I have no idea, why it is showing such behavior, and after a lot of scavenging, online I couldn't find any fruitful solution.